# wcf custom header working on one server and not the other

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that I have added custom headers to via IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest.  When I send from the original server (running server 2003 and asp .net 4.0) it works fine, the header is included.

I just moved this to another server for a client and the header does NOT show up.  This server is 2008 R2 64-bit with net 4.0.  The code and web.config are 100% the same.  What possible difference in the server could be causing this?

Note that there are no errors or anything, it simply does NOT add the header.  In addition, this other server has the IIS issue where the asp .net tab does not show up.  I am unable to resolve that so instead used aspnet_regiis to set all the applications to 4.0.  Everything works fine and dandy except it does not include the header.

Comment: Did you use a utility like Wireshark to look at the actual packets and see what is actually being transmitted from both?

Comment: Yes thats how Im determining its missing.